# Is it okay to use AsyncTask like this:

Tags: android, android-asynctask

As I said, is this a correct use of AsyncTask ?

I mean, without using any parameters, passing the activity context on the `onPreExecute()`, and not getting the result of the `doInBackground()` returned value, but the manager itself once the `onPostExecute()` is called.

And one more thing, Asynctask API Reference it's said about `onPostExecute()`:  "This method won't be invoked if the task was cancelled." , so what about if SomeException happens while doing the `doInBackground()` method, ¿Is `onPostExecuted()` called?

```
public class MainClass {
    ...
    //Somewhere in the class, the task is called:
    new MyAsyncTask.execute();
    ...

    private class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask <Void,Void,Void> {

        private MyManager manager;

        protected void onPreExecute(){
            super.onPreExecute();
            //We initialice the members here, passing the context like this:
            manager = new Manager(MainClass.this);
            manager.initializeMembers();
        }

        protected void doInBackgroud(Void ...params){
            try{
                //here we use the long operation task that is inside the manager:
                manager.startLongTask();                
            } catch (SomeException e){
                doWhatEverItIsWith(e);
            }
            return null;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute (Void result){
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            //Here we get the result from the manager
            handleTheResultFromHere(manager.getResult());
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> As I said, is this a correct use of AsyncTask ?

Yes, its ok to pass the Activity context in `onPreExecute()` and then loading the data in `doInBackgroud()` and updating the UI in `onPostExecute()`.

> so what about if SomeException happens while doing the
>   doInBackground() method, ¿Is onPostExecuted() called?

Yes, `onPreExecute()` will be called if you get any exception in `doInBackgroud()`. You have to check the data to be loaded in `onPreExecute()` checking if the data is not null and update the UI.

```
NOTE:
```

Never try to update UI from `doInBackgroud()` it will give you exception as you can't update UI from a non-UI thread. Alternate is to use `Handler` or `runOnUIThread()` for updating UI from a non-UI Thread.

Answer (score 1):

There is no problem in using AsyncTask like this. You don't have to use `doInBackground` return value. Concerning second question, yes `onPostExecute` will be called even in case of exception. If you don't want to call it, you would have to use `MyAsyncTask.cancel(true)`